# no operator error when used Vector with class

Tags: c++, class, vector

I created a for loop to print entered students' information but when I printed them out by using `cout << st.printInfo() << endl;`, I got `no operator "<<" matches these operants`

Student class:

```
class Student {
private:
    string nameSurname;
    int score;

public:
    void printInfo();
    void setName(string _nameSurname) { nameSurname = _nameSurname; }
    void setScore(int _score) { score = _score; }
    Student() {
        nameSurname = "Not Entered";
        score = 0;
    }
    ~Student() {}
};
```

Function for printing :

```
void Student::printInfo()
{
    cout << "-----------------" << endl;
    cout << "Name and Surname : " << nameSurname << endl;
    cout << "Score : " << score << endl;
    cout << "-----------------" << endl;
}
```

Main Function:

```
vector<Student> v;
    string nameSurname;
    int score;
    Student st;
for (int i = 0; i < v.size() + 1; i++)
        {
            cout << "Enter " << i + 1 << " Student Name and Surname : " << endl;
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, nameSurname);
            st.setName(nameSurname);
            cout << "Enter Student's Score : " << endl;
            cin >> score;
            st.setScore(score);
            v.push_back(st);
        }
```

The error was revealed inside for loop part which is below. That for loop is also in main function.

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << st.printInfo() << endl;
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't find the `operator<<` and that operator doesn't exist indeed. Strange.

Comment: @skypjack:  hint:  evaluate the `st.printInfo()` before applying it to the `cout`.

Comment: Oh, my fault, didn't see that he was using `printInfo`. Sorry. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `printInfo` function returns `void` and the `std::ostream` has no facilities for printing `void`.

Change your `printInfo` to return a value.
Or call your `printInfo` function alone.
Or pass an `std::ostream` to your `printInfo` function.

The best method would be to overload `operator<<` in your `Student` class.

**Edit 1:** Specifics:
Your `for` loop should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
{
    v[i].printInfo();
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Just changed content of for loop and worked. Thank you for your help. But I did not use overload operator<<. Should I use it? If so, why ?

Comment: I recommend overloading `operator<<` and `operator>>`.  Remember, if the answer is helpful, click on the check mark.  If you overload the operators, you can do: `cout << v[i] << endl;`.

Comment: Thanks, l'll take a look for operators.